# Generate a class diagram from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, diagram, class-diagram

I would like to generate a class diagram with relations for my visual studio project. I opened my solution, added a new `ModelingProject`, added a new `.classdiagram` file but when i want to drag my folders or my classes onto the diagram layout I get the "not available" sign.

Does anyone has any idea on how to fix this ?

[image: Prove]

Comment: [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx) from MSDN might be helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate class diagram from project in Visual Studio 2013?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873489/how-to-generate-class-diagram-from-project-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/designing-and-viewing-classes-and-types?view=vs-2022) is the up-to-date msdn how-to article .

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For generating the class diagram Visual Studio is providing the in-built option please use that, Go to **class view window** of your project, **RightClick** -> select **View** -> click on  **View Class Diagram**. This will generate a class diagram for your project.

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff657806(v=vs.140)
- [How to generate class diagram from project in Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20873489/)

Thanks

Comment: There is no such menu option.

Comment: What is the version of your VS?

Comment: See if this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233831/class-diagrams-in-vs-2017

Comment: I found no Project's View context menu as well. Nevertheless, in Visual Studio 2019, dragging the whole project to an empty class diagram (add new item -> class diagram) will do the job.

Comment: You have to open de Visual Studio Installer -> Modify your installation of VS -> Add from individual components, the Class Diagram option. Then you will see the option.

Answer (score 138):

**For Visual Studio 2017, 2019 and 2022**

---

This feature is still available, but it is **NOT** installed by default, you have to install it separately.

1. From inside Visual Studio go to **Tools** -> **Get Tools and Features**
2. Select the **Individual components** tab and search for **Class Designer**
3. Check this Component and Install it

[image]

After finish installing this component

1. Right-click on the project and select Add -> Add New Item
   A. Search for 'class' word and **NOW you can see Class Diagram component**

[image]

**Very Important Update From the Comments below**

1. Right-clicking on a folder and selecting `Add New Item` will **NOT** show the `Class Diagram` option. 
   You could right-click on a project.
2. Not every project type will support `Class Diagram` For example,
   Right-clicking on `Class Library` project will **DO** show `Class Diagram` option in the `Add New Item` dialog.

   But Right-clicking on `ASP.NET` project will **NOT** show `Class Diagram` option in the `Add New Item` dialog.

Comment: I did install Class Designer, but the template does not appear to me. Any clues?

Comment: @GuillemPoy Restart Visual Studio and if available the PC

Comment: I did find out that it was because I was not in a "project" but in a folder.

Comment: Yes, I have installed the Class Designer but can't find the template

Comment: Try thins: https://fmoralesdev.com/2019/05/16/generate-class-diagram-vs2019-net-core/

Comment: @yogibear restart VS and PC and make sure to make search fo the right element in the Add Item Dialog

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes restarting and then trying the manual workaround by add .cd and editing the initial xml works. Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks @HakanFıstık for suggesting. It was really very helpful.

Comment: this seems to do not work for me, neither 2017 and 2019

Comment: @Lotan thanks for the feedback can be more specific about why it did not work for you and did you try to restart VS?

Comment: @HakanFıstık hi Hakan, I've tried with 2017 and 2019, I can install the package, but the Diagram Class element do not show, I've tried the fake-XML approach on the link above, but it doesn't work, simply don't show the element :( I've tried to restart VS and PC and no change

Comment: @Lotan Hi sorry for late response, see my update on the answer, I hope it will solve your problem

Comment: @HakanFıstık You're right, I need to target the Assembly not the project itself, now it seems to work, thanks! ^^

Comment: It's a beautiful design ;-).  If you want to add a class designer to a web project, you can add it first to a class library and then move it to your web project.

Comment: suggesting also the Code Map feature in VS 2022!