# How to generate class diagram from project in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2010 I can generate class diagram from my project with 2 clicks. But now in Visual Studio 2013 I don't see the option "View Class Diagram" in project menu. Where did this item disappear? How can I generate class diagram from project now?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Right click on the project in solution explorer or class view window --> "View" --> "View Class Diagram"

Comment: this is not really UML

Comment: I want to give this diagram to my client, but not code, what should I do?

Comment: For Visual Studio 2019/2017 this will **NOT** work, see my answer below Visual Studio 2019/2017

Answer (score 23):

For creating real UML class diagrams:

In Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate you can do this without any external tools.

- In the menu, click on **Architecture**, **New Diagram**
  Select **UML Class Diagram**
- This will ask you to create a new **Modeling Project** if you don't have one already.

You will have a empty UMLClassDiagram.classdiagram.

- Again, go to **Architecture**, **Windows**, **Architecture Explorer**.
- A window will pop up with your namespaces, Choose **Class View**.
- Then a list of sub-namespaces will appear, if any. Choose one, select the classes and drag them to the empty UMLClassDiagram1.classdiagram window.

[Reference: Create UML Class Diagrams from Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx)

Comment: For Visual studio 2015, the Architecture window is only available in the Ultimate version.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no VS2015 ultimate edition. Maybe you mean Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 7):

**For Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio 2017 Users** 
*For People who are missing this old feature in VS2019 (or maybe VS2017) from the old versions of Visual Studio*

---

This feature still available, but it is **NOT** available by default, you have to install it separately.

1. Open VS 2019 go to **Tools** -> **Get Tools and Features**
2. Select the **Individual components** tab and search for **Class Designer**
3. Select this Component and Install it, After finish installing this component (you may need to restart visual studio)
4. Right-click on the project and select Add -> Add New Item
5. Search for 'class' word and **NOW you can see Class Diagram component**

see this answer also to see an image associated

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289543/4390133

*(whish that the moderator realized this is the same question and instead of deleting my answer, he could mark one of the questions as duplicated to the other)*

---

**Update to create a class-diagram for the whole project** 
Here is how to generate a diagram for the whole project (after applying the previous steps)

1. Add class diagram to the project
2. if the option `Preview Selected Items` is enabled in the solution explorer, disabled it temporarily, you can re-enable it later

[image]

3. open the class diagram that you created in step 2 (by double-clicking on it)
4. drag-and-drop the project from the solution explorer to the class diagram