# “collections were modified enumeration operation may not execute” in Class diagram

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I want to understand the Rx code better by using its UML diagram. Then I use VS2013 community to generate it. But it failed.

A dialogue occurs with the sentence "collections were modified;enumeration operation may not execute". What is the reason? And how to correct it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873489/how-to-generate-uml-class-diagram-from-project-in-visual-studio-2013   I do as the webpage describes.

Comment: I'm pretty certain you won't be able to do this with Rx as it is more functional in nature and has many closures (auto generated classes). You'll find that the classes generated are far more complex than the Rx operators are. What is it you're trying to understand?

Comment: Thx, Enigmativity. I want to totally understand the structure of Rx and how to use it. Then I need to make some extensions to Rx not for my own interest but for a task from others. Now I  think I will not get get the UML diagram.

Comment: I really don't think the UML diagram will help. Have you watched the excellent videos on Microsoft's Channel 9? http://channel9.msdn.com/Search?term=Rx#ch9Search

Comment: No. Do you think it will useful for the beginner of the Rx?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. It would be very good. Especially the stuff with regard to duality with enumerables and the discussions on the "contract" for observers.