# Generating UML diagram from project file in Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: uml, visual-studio-exp-2013

How can I generate UML diagram from c++ project file in Visual Studio Express 2013. I have read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873489/how-to-generate-class-diagram-from-project-in-visual-studio-2013), however I cannot find the "View" option anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure you're right clicking the project as opposed to the solution?

Comment: Here is how it looks: http://s28.postimg.org/ewyo441m5/Untitled.png

Comment: Do you have an imgur link?

Comment: here: http://i.imgur.com/evElunz.png

Comment: Oh it looks like its not available for vs express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class diagrams are not available for Visual Studio Express.

Source:https://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs

Under Architecture and Modeling > UML® 2.0 Compliant Diagrams (Activity, Use Case, Sequence, Class, and Component), it is not available for VS community, which is at the same level of express. This is for 2015, but is the same for 2013.

Additional Links for other versions:

[VS2010](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?522353-Class-Diagram-in-C-2010-Express&p=2061115#post2061115)

> It's not there in Express version.

[VS2012](http://csharp.2000things.com/2013/01/11/756-viewing-a-class-diagram-in-visual-studio-2012/)

> No, unfortunately, I think that you can only do this in the Premium or Ultimate editions. :O(