# VS 2015, class diagram

Tags: c#, class, uml, diagram

I am wondering how to create the UML class diagram from code. I've searched for it, but all I've found is either tutorials on how to make it by myself or advices to choose "View Class Diagram", but it doesn't create the UML class diagram with UML standards, it rather displays it with VS's own icons for classes, methods, etc. I am using VS NET 2015 Enterprise Edition. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Well in vs2013 it was possible, I just can't find the right button to complete these steps http://stackoverflow.com/a/30507875/2901207

Comment: I have the same problem. I have created `*.classdiagram`, but I cannot move any of my class into it from the `ClassView`.

Comment: Ok, I've found it is not supported in VS 2015. To be able it another installation of VS 2013 is needed...

Comment: You might give that as answer to self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer is not completely correct.  This feature is available in Visual Studio 2015 **Enterprise** edition (equivalent to Visual Studio Ultimate).

According to the [VS 2015 Edition Comparison](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx), there are 4 components for Architecture and Modeling:

1. Architectual Layer Diagrams
2. Architecture Validation
3. UML® 2.0 Compliant Diagrams (Activity, Use Case, Sequence, Class, and Component)
4. Visualize solutions with Dependency Graphs and Code Maps

Entrprise edition supports all 4.  Community and Professional only support #4, but can open diagrams created in earlier editions of VS in read-only mode.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found it is not supported in VS 2015. To be able it another installation of VS 2013 is needed...