# Class diagram in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, uml, class-diagram

I have made class diagram as describes in the answer of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873489/how-to-generate-class-diagram-from-project-in-visual-studio-2013)

But the problem with this class diagram is that it is linked with code and not able to open without code. If I transfer my `diagram.cd` to another pc and try to open it, error occurred stating that put it back in project and then try to open.

I don't want to give code to someone but this diagram. Please help if it possible by any other means. But I don't want to make these diagrams in visio.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that is so easy, right clicking the diagram in visual studio shows me option to export to image and it created a nice and big png image. And off course it is accessible without visual studio. :)