# Generating class diagrams with relationships between them from existing classes in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class-diagram

I've many classes written in C#.NET in my solution. I need  something like a class diagram along with the relation-ships between the existing classes using Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you tried googling this before posting here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate class diagram from project in Visual Studio 2013?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873489/how-to-generate-class-diagram-from-project-in-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 0):

try inheritance to create the class relationships

example:

```
Public class Vehicels
{}

public class Car : Vehicels
{}
```

Comment: Already classes are there in the solution with the relationships. Now I want to generate the class diagram from the class along with the existing relationships. I heard that PowerToys helps in this scenario but not sure how!

Answer (score 0):

Considering using "View Class Diagram" in Visual Studio.

More information on Adding a Class Diagram to your project can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyxd8c85.aspx