# Is Visual Studio 2017 new .csproj relevant to non .net core projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, csproj

I'm a bit confused.
I have the new version of Visual Studio 2017.
And have converted my class projects (.net full 4.5) to the new .csproj project format. Then I tried to run live tests on those projects, but VS now informs me that live testing is not supported on .net core projects jet.

So:

1. Are those projects now .Net Core projects?
2. If Yes, can I use the new .csproj project file for the old good .Net Full 4.x
3. I am planning to deploy my application as WebApi services to a windows server only, and I'm planning to use NHibernate ORM, so movig to .net Core is excluded, are there any benefit of using this new .csproj format for my case?
4. Can I use the new .csproj format and keep using non .Net Core compatible libraries like NHibernate?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably consider using .NET Standard as your portable class libraries, if the API provided is enough for you. Then you can reference it in all types of projects, full .NET Framework or .NET Core.

Comment: Ok, You didn't answer any of my question, also I wrote in my post that I plan to use NHibernate which is NOT .Net core and .Net standard compatible.

Comment: I didn't, that's why I posted a comment, not an answer. Sorry for trying to help.

Comment: Hi, I'm currently asking me the same question. Do you have any updates on this ?

Comment: With the latest update to VS 2017, all projects are converted in the new .csproj file format. And yes, you can still use the full .net framework ie (.net framework 4.7.1).

Answer (score 6):

I like the new format for .net 4.0 projects, it's way easier not having to worry about including files to your project also having less files to deal with nuget is nice as well.

You can start out with a `csproj` as simple as this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net40</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

And then use visual studio to add back in your dependencies, move the meta data to the packages tab and remove `AssemblyInfo.cs`, and then customize anything you had custom *(hint sometimes excluding and re-including files can help to get the default behavior if you have something strange e.g. T4 templates)*. It will be a much cleaner file and way easier to update to .netstandard in the future (or even multitarget).

Here is an example of an opensource project of mine using multi-target and some T4 templates this is the full file and there are like 40 C# files automatically included in the project because they are in the directory:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.5;net40</TargetFrameworks>
        <Description>(pronounced dyna-mighty) flexes DLR muscle to do meta-mazing things in .net</Description>
        <Company>Ekon Benefits</Company>
        <Authors/>
        <Copyright>Copyright 2017 Ekon Benefits</Copyright>
        <AssemblyVersion>1.5.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
        <FileVersion>1.5.0.0</FileVersion>
        <PackageProjectUrl>https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey</PackageProjectUrl>
        <PackageLicenseUrl>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</PackageLicenseUrl>
        <PackageTags>dynamic metaprogramming dlr reflection currying tuples expando latetypes</PackageTags>
        <IncludeSymbols>True</IncludeSymbols>
        <IncludeSource>True</IncludeSource>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
        <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>True</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
        <SignAssembly>True</SignAssembly>
        <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>sn.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
        <DelaySign>False</DelaySign>
        <Version>1.5.0</Version>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'!='net40'">
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.3.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel" Version="4.3.0"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net40'">
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="InlineLambdas.tt">
            <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
            <LastGenOutput>InlineLambdas.cs</LastGenOutput>
        </None>
        <None Update="ThisFunctions.tt">
            <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
            <LastGenOutput>ThisFunctions.cs</LastGenOutput>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Update="InlineLambdas.cs">
            <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
            <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
            <DependentUpon>InlineLambdas.tt</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
        <Compile Update="ThisFunctions.cs">
            <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
            <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
            <DependentUpon>ThisFunctions.tt</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Oh I like it, but I don't understand some things ie.:
1. Why there is no template for .net FULL framework for this new .csproj type, only for .net core and .net standard.

Comment: 2. If I want to create class diagrams from classes, it says that this project type is not compatible with the format.

Comment: 3. If I remove AssemblyInfo file, then what about InternalsVisibleTo assembly attribute, where to put it?

Comment: 1. I don't know why there isn't a VS template you can just add, but they don't have any GUI for creating multi-targeting, but once you make it, the GUI works great with it, it's how I figured out a lot of options.

Comment: 2.Class diagrams seems like it's own question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233831/class-diagrams-in-vs-2017

Comment: 3. InternalsVisibleTo is an assembly attribute. So it can be in any file, make an InternalsInfo.cs, all the other metadata version etc is going to be compiled from a build generated file, so as long as it doesn't conflict you are fine to add whatever you want.

Comment: thanks about the info on InternalsVisibleTo. I move some of my projects to the new .csproj files, but there seems that it's not mature enought. Ie. I can't use live testing on this new project type, it complains that it is not supported on .net core. It seems that Visual studio thisnks of this new .csproj format as .net core projects.

Comment: @Luka Yeah in that specific case it's too early, this is probably related to the fact this is the new Rosyln Project System https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-project-system

Comment: Anyone know how to do an assembly binding redirect with this new csproj? I'm getting an issue with multiple System.Net.Http versions installed.

Comment: @Dagrooms that sounds like it might be an issue with `Microsoft.BCL`, either way that should be asked as a new question SO with more specific details of your build file.

Comment: @jbtule I opened an issue on github, turns out signalR 2.2.1 stable defines the system.net.http namespace, but 2.2.2 doesn't. Really nice bug