# Can't find the Class Diagram in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uml, visual-studio-2017, class-diagram

I've installed Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise on my computer with the Installer and there are some optional options like the "Class-Diagram". 
I've checked it but it won't show up in my project templates.

Programm language: C#

Version VS 2017: 15.0.26228.9

Version VS Installer: 1.5.30308.1

[VS Installer - Class Diagram is checked and already installed (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NczH.png)

[On the left hand side, we can't find the category "Model Project" like in VS 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J16Qs.png)

Regards

Comment: You can follow this link:
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyxd8c85.aspx][1]

Comment: It's not, it's just formed badly; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyxd8c85.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class Diagrams in VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233831/class-diagrams-in-vs-2017)

Comment: @RoshanGhangare it doesn't matter due to my question is anwsered and his is still open.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems the 'modelling project' feature is removed from Visual Studio 2017. Reasons are given here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/10/14/uml-designers-have-been-removed-layer-designer-now-supports-live-architectural-analysis/

Answer (score 4):

Have you added the Visual Studio extension development?

Along with Class Designer, you have to include Visual Studio extension development also from the VS2017 installer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed all the required things mentioned above and if you are still not seeing the Class Diagram from Solution Explorer , switch to Class View and then you will see the "View Class Diagram" option