# Visual Studio Community for Mac os

Tags: c#, macos, class-diagram, visual-studio-mac

i am looking for the class diagram in Visual Studio Community 2017 on Mac os and I can't seem to find it, Anybody knows where it's at?

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class Diagrams in VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233831/class-diagrams-in-vs-2017)

Comment: VS for Windows features are not necessarily available in VS for Mac.

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac does not currently have support for class diagrams. You can vote on [Visual Studio for Mac's user voice site](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/32886142-class-diagrams-for-c-projects) for this feature.