# Unable to open class diagram in designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, class-diagram

## Unable to open CustomerClasses.cd in designer

Learning C#, WPF and Visual Studio, in a demo project I have these 2 class diagram files:

- CustomerClasses.cd - opens in code view only
- ViewModelClasses.cd - opens in designer view only

Note: files available from here https://github.com/puckchaser/MvvmDemoApp/tree/master/DemoApp/Class%20Diagrams

First challenge was installing the designer feature, see here: [Class Diagrams in VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233831/class-diagrams-in-vs-2017)

The right click context menus for both files *(via solution explorer)* are different. From reading around I gather that a probable reason that CustomerClasses does NOT open in designer view is due to malformed XML, but neither I nor (as far as I can tell) Visual Studio is able to find any issue.

[image: What I see]

> ***Image shows*** CustomerClasses.cd (left) displayed as code and ViewModelClasses.cd (right) displayed as diagram. Menu for CustomerClasses.cd  (far right) does not work.

---

### But it is shown in the related article...

I believe that I should be able to see the design view because it is shown in the related article as figure 11: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> [image: Related article showing the missing diagram]

Furthermore, the xml of the file seems to correspond to what is shown in the diagram... *this is driving me nuts*

---

FWIW - this is one of the best walk-throughs I've come across for learning WPF in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fixed but not sure why

I downloaded the source files from github (which happens to be a different source than originally used) https://github.com/puckchaser/MvvmDemoApp and tried again, this time it works.

I used version control to try and identify the root cause of the issue but I don't see anything that explains this to me. There were changes in the file: DemoApp.csproj but I don't know if they could explain this :-/