# How to create relationship diagram from .cs files in Models directory

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have just used the Scaffold-DbContext command to generate a set of .cs files from an SQL Server database using EntityFrameworkCore and put them into a directory called Models.

Is there any way I can create an entity relationship diagram from the .cs files in the Models directory?

I recall I could do that in EntityFamework by selecting from the right click menu on Models but those features don't seem to be there for EntityFrameworkCore.

Can anyone help?

First I need to thank M. Mohabbati and Gert Arnold for their responses.

I need to add that I can see the Class Diagram for WPF and Console Apps but not for a Blazor app - see below ....
[image]

Following the link  [provided by Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17191218/861716) I get to this  [link provided by yogibear](https://fmoralesdev.com/2019/05/16/generate-class-diagram-vs2019-net-core/) that allows me to at least drag classes into the .cd file.

But boy, what a crock.

Can anyon tell me why I can't see and add the Class Diagram my Blazor App and why I have to follow Franco Morales amazing and torurous route to get anywhere?

Congratulations on discovering the method Franco, but why did you have to?

Comment: Create a class diagram in Visual Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17191218/861716

Comment: Class Designer is not available in .NET Core projects. Use Class Library project instead. [Design and view classes and types with Class Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/designing-and-viewing-classes-and-types?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Thanks Mohabbati.  That does me for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install **Class Designer** from *Visual Studio Installer*. Modify Visual Studio then go to *Individual Components* and find Class Designer.

Then add **Class Diagram** from *Add --> New Item...*.

In the designer, you can add all classes you need. By default, there is no arrow to show the relations for example Inheritance or Composition association relationships.

By right-clicking on a class, you can show **Base** or **Derived** classes. And by right-clicking on a property you can show as **Association**.

NOTE: Class Designer is not available in .NET Core projects. Use Class Library project instead:
[Design and view classes and types with Class Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/designing-and-viewing-classes-and-types?view=vs-2022)

[How to: Add class diagrams to projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/how-to-add-class-diagrams-to-projects?view=vs-2022)